# How to divide columns into even more columns?

Tags: multicol, columns

I want to add a two-column chapter to a document (have been using `multicol` when necessary throughout the whole document) which has a "four-column" section just after a short first paragraph. The four-column part will then span a couple of pages.

The thing is that what I need is to actually divide two columns into four, without breaking the flow of the document, so that, when the further divided text ends, it doesn't split into four columns and span the whole width of the page, but rather go back into the original two-column state. So, it's not actually four columns that I'm looking for, but a two-column text within two-column text. Something like in the example that inspired the whole idea:
[image]

I've already tried `\twocolumn`+`multicol` and using `multicol` within `multicol`, but the first one produces text only on the left side of the page, and the second one is even worse.

Is there a way to further divide a set number of columns and keep it for a couple of pages?

Comment: Well, it basically disturbs the flow of the text in my opinion, and the example that I've added above shows what I want to achieve, a kind of continuity.